# Starting node-huxley with example tests

Tags: node.js, selenium

I'm struggling to get node-huxley to run. Having installed it globally, I then installed the node-selenium driver, cloned the repo and tried to run Huxley on the examples. However I'm seeing this error.

It seems to suggest that the server isn't running, but I've verified it as running on localhost:8000 correctly. Any ideas how to debug this?

```
firefox opening.

At 1 type and toggle.hux

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/huxley/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1549
      throw error;
            ^
Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/huxley/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:127:16)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1547:9)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:440:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
==== async task ====
WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/huxley/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:131:49)
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/huxley/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:111:30)
    at Builder.build (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/huxley/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:105:20)
    at _open (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/huxley/source/browser/driver.js:28:6)
    at Object.open (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/huxley/source/browser/driver.js:49:3)
    at _openRunAndClose (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/huxley/index.js:76:11)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/huxley/index.js:169:5
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/huxley/index.js:217:5
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/huxley/source/playback/getPlaybackInfos.js:121:5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you started selenium? (https://github.com/chenglou/node-huxley#installation)

Comment: Ah there you go. I'd not used Selenium before, so it never occurred to me to actually, you know, start it! Thank you.

Comment: Np. I stumbled upon this question by accident though. If you have other issues you can post them on github.